# define model association without the second model

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way in CakePHP 1.3 to define a model association without having a model for the associated table? For example:

```
<?php

    class SomeModel extends AppModel 
    {
        var $useTable = 'some_table';

        var $belongsTo = array(
            'AnotherModel' => array(
                // association data here
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

Where `AnotherModel` doesn't actually have a model file. I just want to define the table that model would use and the association details. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is: It should be fine. Have you tried it? Worse case scenario is it won't work without the file, so just add the model file. It takes all of two seconds:

```
<?php
class AnotherModel extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'AnotherModel';
}
?>
```

Done!

**UPDATE**

If you follow cake convention on the naming of tables, you should be able to reference the table using the appropriate name without the model file. For example:

- my_models  =  MyModel
- your_models = YourModel
- model_tables = TableModel

However, if you have a table that does not follow convention, you must create a model file that defines `$useTable` to indicate which table it relates to:

- some_table  =  model file: `SomeTable` where `$useTable = 'some_table';`
- another_model = model file: `CustomModel` where `$userTable = 'anotherModel';`

There is no other way around it. CakePHP is not magic. It needs to know what table is being referenced. Unless you are doing joins. Then in the join you can reference the table.

Comment: How do I define the table the association uses though? Also, I don't want to create a model file because there are approx 8 -11 associated tables, none of which would ever be accessed except through the main model.

Comment: The table name would be `another_models`. I don't follow. Are you saying to want to write code without providing all of the requirements and you expect it work? Just because you provide the model file does not mean you need to include all of the associated relationships inside each file.

Comment: No, i need to tell cakephp what the name of the table is. AnotherModel might use a table called `some_table`. But i dont want to create a model file for `AnotherModel`. Im guessing i want to achievijg the same effect as when you dynamically bind a non-existant model

Comment: You can't build a relationship for a table that is not defined anywhere unless you follow the proper conventions. For example: If you have a table named `some_models`, you should be able to reference the model as `SomeModel` in a relationship in another model without the SomeModel model. However, if you have a table named `my_other_table`, there is no way to reference that table anywhere without creating the model file.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding. Are you looking to associate external data (data that is not even in a database) to the model? If so, this would require a datasource.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I need to use the table names that are already in place. Also, I have models in place that would be more work to rename them everywhere in my code than to create a new model file. Thanks for your help.